# Spring Data - Paging parameters being ignored

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an issue where paging is not being considered in calls to a PagingAndSortingRepository. In the below call, the list returned is of size 3 (this page_size + 2 is consistent no matter what page size I specify), and the first page is always returned.

The database has 10 elements at time of testing

```
PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(1, 1);
List<Review> reviews = reviewRepository.findOwner(id, page).toList();
```

**findOwner()**

```
@Query( value = "SELECT r FROM Review r INNER JOIN FETCH r.owner WHERE r.owner.id IN (:ids)",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Review r INNER JOIN r.owner WHERE r.owner.id IN (:ids)")
    List<Review> findByOwner(@Param("ids") List<Long> managedUserIdList, Pageable page);
```

**SQL Output**

```
Hibernate: select r1_0.review_id, r1_0.caption1, r1_0.caption2, r1_0.caption3, r1_0.date, o2_0.id, o2_0.bodysize_id, o2_0.regDate, o2_0.screenname, o2_0.user_id, r1_0.status, r1_0.url from review as r1_0 inner join ManagedUser as o1_0 on r1_0.owner = o1_0.id left outer join ManagedUser as o2_0 on r1_0.owner = o2_0.id where o2_0.id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select b1_0.id, b1_0.ankle, b1_0.armLength, b1_0.bust, b1_0.calf, b1_0.chest, b1_0.hairColour, b1_0.hairStyle, b1_0.height, b1_0.hip, b1_0.legLength, b1_0.neck, b1_0.shoulder, b1_0.skinTone, b1_0.thigh, b1_0.upperArm, b1_0.waist, b1_0.weight, b1_0.wrist, m1_0.id, m1_0.regDate, m1_0.screenname, u1_0.user_id, u1_0.country, u1_0.email, u1_0.password, u1_0.points, p1_0.id, p1_0.bodysize_id, p1_0.regDate, p1_0.screenname, p1_0.user_id, u1_0.userLevel from bodysize as b1_0 left outer join ManagedUser as m1_0 on b1_0.id = m1_0.bodysize_id inner join UserAccount as u1_0 on m1_0.user_id = u1_0.user_id left outer join ManagedUser as p1_0 on u1_0.primaryUser_id = p1_0.id where b1_0.id = ?
Hibernate: select b1_0.id, b1_0.ankle, b1_0.armLength, b1_0.bust, b1_0.calf, b1_0.chest, b1_0.hairColour, b1_0.hairStyle, b1_0.height, b1_0.hip, b1_0.legLength, b1_0.neck, b1_0.shoulder, b1_0.skinTone, b1_0.thigh, b1_0.upperArm, b1_0.waist, b1_0.weight, b1_0.wrist, m1_0.id, m1_0.regDate, m1_0.screenname, u1_0.user_id, u1_0.country, u1_0.email, u1_0.password, u1_0.points, p1_0.id, p1_0.bodysize_id, p1_0.regDate, p1_0.screenname, p1_0.user_id, u1_0.userLevel from bodysize as b1_0 left outer join ManagedUser as m1_0 on b1_0.id = m1_0.bodysize_id inner join UserAccount as u1_0 on m1_0.user_id = u1_0.user_id left outer join ManagedUser as p1_0 on u1_0.primaryUser_id = p1_0.id where b1_0.id = ?
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please show the declaration of `findOwner` and all the SQL that gets executed.

Comment: @JensSchauder Added the findOwner declaration and Hibernate debug output. Of note is that the findAll(Pagination page) has the same issue for the reviewRepository

Comment: Hi @FinnTorbet - I am just confused on the methods where you post **findByOwner** is this now being used instead of your **findOwner** original declaration? Also, when you are attempting to use pagination you need to make sure your **reviewRepository** is extending JpaRepository (or PagingAndSortingRepository) to use pagination. Now you can remove the **countQuery** part and change your return type on your query method **findByOwner** to **Page<Review>**.